# Configuring the route of an HttpGet attribute

Tags: asp.net-core

For some reason I'm struggling customizing the route of an ASP.NET CORE 3 HttpGet attribute.

If the controller has :[Route("api/[myroute]")]

and I use :  [HttpGet("logon/{id}")] for my controller function

Shouldn't that automatically create a route api/[myroute]/logon/id

For some reason I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

[controller] is replaced with the controller name.

If not using token attribute for method i.e. [action] then your method should match the route string in the HttpGet e.g:

```
[HttpGet("GetItem/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetItem(int id)
```